# Merging new `mod_rewrite` rules and preserving old behaviour, what is wrong?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using Apache2 with the following (good) `.htaccess` at the root of my site,

```
 #OLD (GOOD, IS WORKING!)
 # If requested url is an existing file or folder, don't touch it
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule . - [L]

 RewriteRule ^(urn|URN):(.+)$     index.php?urn=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\d\-]+)$    index.php?obj=$1 [L]
```

Now I need to merge a new condition for the folder xWiki

```
#NEW: some conflicts, how to preserve old and add /xWiki* behaviour?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^xWiki/?(.*)$ /xWiki/index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**How to "merge" preserving old behaviour except to `/xWiki`?**

Only adding the `RewriteRule ^xWiki/?(.*)$` not works, and the `!-f`  is in conflict with the same `-f` cond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
 #OLD (GOOD, IS WORKING!)
 # If requested url is an existing file or folder, don't touch it
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule . - [L]

 RewriteRule ^xWiki/(.*)$ /xWiki/index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]

 RewriteRule ^(urn|URN):(.+)$     index.php?urn=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\d\-]+)$    index.php?obj=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- the main issue is to place the `RewriteRule` in the correct place (before other RewriteRules), and undertand that there are no conflict with `-f` and `!-f` (no changes in the `-f` is the merge solution).
- a good optimization was to change regex `^xWiki/?(.*)$` to `^xWiki/(.*)$`.

Comment: Plase read the question, as I say, "Only adding the RewriteRule `^xWiki/?(.*)$` not works"... Please explain why you think it must work, or what more can be wrong to not work for me.

Comment: Do you seriously believe I answered without reading? Why I believe this answer will work because of 2 reasons: 1) Right sequence of rules where `xwiki` rule must be after 1st ignore rule and 2) Incorrect regex in your rule where `^xWiki/?(.*)$` will also match for `/xWiki-123-foo` not just `/xWiki/`

Comment: Real problem is regex `xWiki/(.*)` not just matches `/xWiki/abc` it also matches rewritten URI i.e. `/xWiki/index.php` without safeguard of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition. Since I am placing it below `file/folder` rule that's why it will work without that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition.